# Write Line to a specific Index in R

Tags: r, text, writetofile, readlines

How can I write a line to a specific index in a text-file in R?

I use `readLines("ini.ini")` to read my file (using R. 3.3.1 so this won't work: [iniFile](http://search.r-project.org/usr/share/doc/library/raster/html/iniFile.html))

Then I find my lines that I want to change with "regex" and now want to change it in my file.

Any suggestion on how I can do it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible by just changing the specific index into your new text and then write it into the same or new file.

```
a <- readLines("ini.ini")
a[my_specific_line_found_by_grep] <- 'new text'
writeLines(a, 'ini2.ini')
```